# dev C++ compiles but not running(BLACKSCREEN) for the 1st time

Tags: c++

The program does compile but it is not running (the black screen doesn't show up). I have tried the following steps:

- Reinstall the program after deleting it (didn't work)
- Uninstall the program using YourUninstaller.exe, which is a program that deletes everything even the reg files (didn't work either)

So what happened?

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"hello You~~"<< endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that, whilst taspeotis's advice is good, it's not the answer.

Comment: Dev hasn't been updated in a long time, and uses an old version of gcc.  Look into [Code Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org), or MS VC++ Express Edition.

Comment: When you say "BLACK SCREEN" presumably you mean the terminal window that your Dev-C++ **IDE** invokes to run the program after building it with the MinGW GCC **compiler**. Are you sure you hit "Run" as well as "Build"?

Comment: For a fairly portable 'pause' function, just use `cin.get()`. It's (usually) dismissed by simply pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

`conio.h` and at the end of the program `getch();`.

This helped me with the same problem in Borland C++ installed on win xp on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your anti-virus, its blocking your binaries.

Reinstall dev c++ when your antivirus is disabled.
After installation enable anti-virus if it blocks again, go add an exception in anti-virus program

Answer (score 0):

Better use `sleep(1)` instead of calling subprocess.

```
cout<<"hello You~~"<< endl;
sleep(1);
```

Edit: `sleep(1)` works fine under *Linux* but as well-suggested 
by @user786653 use of `cin.get()` is recommended, and is closer than `PAUSE`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello You~~" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still the same as not having `Sleep(1)`

Answer (score -1):

The same problem is also faced by me in newest version of Dev
i just uses the header file `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in initial
and with this use `getchar()` just before `return 0` statement in last of program.

it works definitely please remember `getchar()` is just before returen statement , not after return statement.